# thead with translate overlapped by tbody inner div (Chome only)

Tags: css, google-chrome

This happens only in Chrome. This is a super-simplified version of my **very** complex code, and the `thead` (in light blue) should not have the letters ("x", "y", "z") on top of it, as it renders great on Firefox, but on Chrome it seems the inner `div` `position relative` is somehow going over the `thead`.

> The `position:relative` inside a table cell is absolutely imperative
>   to the situation.

How can the `thead` be **over** the `tbody`? 
it seems not to respect any z-index.
I'm aware the `thead` rendered on its own layer because it has a *transform* declared on it, but why isn't that layer above the tbody? and only on Chrome? very strange. couldn't find nothing on Google regarding this.

```css
table > thead {
  background: lightblue;
  z-index: 20;
}

td, th { padding: 2em ;}

table td:first-child > div {
  position: relative;
  background: lightyellow;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead style="transform: translate(0, 50px);">
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>x</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>y</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>z</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### This is how it should look (like on Firefox):

[image]

---

Remember, this is a *simplified* demo where the `thead` has a translate, and this is controlled in reality by JS which isn't included here because it's irrelevant to the issue, and only the hard-coded outcome was written as `<thead style="transform: translate(0, 50px);">`

---

I've managed to bypass the bug structuring the HTML so the `thead` is written **after** the `tbody`, but still, it's not a pretty fix

#### Update

seems like my "solution" for moving the `thead` to be after the `tbody` causes a world of bugs, again only in Chrome (like always) and Chrome renders the table cells with huge padding when the `thead` node is moved down the DOM. right now, I don't see any solution to the layering problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why all this happens. But I found that adding `z-index: -1` to the div sends it back to where it belongs.

Furthermore, it all works exactly the same (at least in Chrome) if I remove the `position: relative;` from the thead, but maybe other browsers need it.

```css
table > thead {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  z-index: 20;
}

td, th { padding: 2em ;}

table td:first-child > div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  background: lightyellow;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead style="transform: translate(0, 50px);">
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div>x</div></td>
      <td><div>y</div></td>
      <td><div>z</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: using the `z-index:-1` doesn't work when the `tr` has a background, which sadly, mine has in my code..otherwise this would be a good solution. it's also unclear to why does the background on the `tr` causes the `div` to be hidden...

Comment: The `div` disappearing behind the `tr` can be fixed (at least in this simple example) by removing its `position:relative` declaration. I'm also getting rather curious what you are even trying to achieve by having this strange combination of a `table` that gives you layout, and then relatively positioned table contents, I presume to escape from or override the layout - not something I would ever try.

Comment: obviously I wouldn't ask this question if the `position:relative` wouldn't be needed.. that is the whole point, maybe it wasn't clear, I will edit my question to make it clearer

Comment: this is a simplified code of a much more complex overall Table component, which has a fixed table header, which moves when scrolled. The `div` with `position:relative` is needed because of inner icons inside it, where, it is known that `td` cannot have `position:relative`.. also, rows can be expanded, which makes things even more complex.

Comment: For the fixed table header, maybe one of these can help: https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu or https://codepen.io/jgx/pen/wiIGc. Also there are several decent 'fixed table header' jQuery plugins. Why re-invent the wheel...

Comment: lol re-invent the wheel... brother, it is I who invented the wheel in the first place back in the old days of JS, many years back.. besides, I know **all** the examples and links in the whole internet regarding fixed headers for tables, and I tell you, they are all amateur work. not close to a real solution. please do try to edit their tables' cells and insert a very large piece of text..

Answer (score 0):

I found this in another answer somewhere for a similar issue. This worked in my case. Now I can use position styles within my td's as needed.

```
table {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

thead {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
}

tbody {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```